# The edges of the tectonic plates

Tags: plate-tectonics

I have read that the edges of the tectonic plates exist at places like: huge mountains and sea trenches, and I wondered if they exist at the mid-oceanic ridges?

Comment: I think you have things backwards.  It's more that things like mountain ranges and ocean trenches exist at plate boundaries, because they are caused by the movement of the plates.  Simplistically, two plates moving away from each other create a rift, moving towards each other they produce subduction trenches and mountain ranges.

Comment: Excellent video: [Plate Tectonics Basics 1](https://youtu.be/6wJBOk9xjto)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**, the edges (boundaries) of [tectonic plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_tectonics) do occur at the mid-oceanic ridges, such as the Mid-Atlantic ridge.

There are three types of tectonic plate boundaries:

- **Transform Boundaries** where the plates slide past each other sideways, such as at the [San Andreas Fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Andreas_Fault).
- **Divergent Boundaries** where the plates are moving apart, such as the [Mid-Atlantic Ridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-Atlantic_Ridge)  and the [East African Rift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_African_Rift).
- **Convergent Boundaries** where one plate slides beneath the other plate, such as the [Andes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andes) mountain range & the Japanese [island
  arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_arc).